# Varriable retain previous assigned value inside a loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I have variables inside stored procedure has a behavior I dont understand, the variables inside a loop retain the previous loop value !!

Here is the stored procedure

```
v_no = 3;
v_counter = 1;
is_special = 1;

  while (:v_counter <= :v_no) do begin

    if (:is_special = 1) then begin

      select tmaster.axis, tdetail.dim_val
        from tdetail
        right outer join tmaster on (tdetail.sp_id = tmaster.sp_id)
        where (tmaster.sp_id = 17) And (tdetail.pos = :v_counter)
        into :v_axis, :v_dim_val;  /* variable retain previous loop values */

        /* ..... more code here */

    end

  end
```

I have here two tables, tmaster as a master table and tdetail as detail table. When executing the `Select` statement alone in the above code with v_counter = 1,2, and 3 should result in

```
axis    dim_val
----------------
X       14
null    null
X       14
```

but instead when v_counter = 2 I get 'X' for `axis` and 14 for `dim_val` !!, as a work around I set both variables to null in the first of each loop directly after the `while` statement, but why the variables `:v_axis` and `:v_dim_val` was not assigned to null when v_counter = 2 and why they retain previous loop values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you actually don't have a record in `tdetail` where `pos = 2`, right? Thus the result of the select query is empty resultset, not row where all fields are `NULL`. As there is no rows in the resultset, there is nothing to assign to the variables (`:v_axis`, `:v_dim_val`) and thus they retain their values.

Comment: Oh Yes no record where pos = 2, is there a way to return null ?

Comment: Yes, you could write an query which returns "null row" but IMO the code would be much harder to read/understand then. Better just init the variables to `NULL` before `select`, thats easy to follow...

Comment: yes but just for information what should this query look like ?

Comment: ie you could union an query which returns NULLs if there is no matching record for your "real query", something like `union
select null, null from rdb$database where not exists(select 1 from tdetail where pos = :v_counter)`